# IF condition not processed

Tags: php, javascript

Please, anyone can help me to understand why if not working?
I echo variable to check out values and i have respective 0 and 1, same IF conditions...
Query works, IF not work...

```
$data = ($_POST);
$cn = $data['cn'];
$email = $data['email'];

$con1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `crm` WHERE cn = '$cn'", $con);
$num_cn = mysql_num_rows($con1);

$con2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `crm_contacts` WHERE email = '$email'", $con);
$num_email = mysql_num_rows($con2);

        echo $num_cn;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $num_email;

 if ($num_cn == "0" && $num_email == "1") {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>"; 
echo "location.href='crm.php?Error=2;"; 
echo "</script>";
 exit;
 }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). As for the question, you're missing a ' in your JavaScript (after "Error=2", should be "Error=2'")

Comment: True. But Mysql functions are still working.

Comment: @Nik They are working but deprecated, they are not the source of the issue it's good advice which is what comments are for (btw, I also cover the source of the issue which is invalid JS syntax)

Comment: Advices are nice, but the best is the needed answer. This comes first, in my opinion.

Comment: @Nik The problem OP is having is a _typo_, as par site rules, this question will be _closed_ and then _deleted_ anyway. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
echo "location.href='crm.php?Error=2;";
```

you are missing the closing `'`:

```
echo "location.href='crm.php?Error=2';";
//                                  ^
```

Comment: Thks Jueecy for your help.